# Django-cms and autoblocks

Tags: django, django-cms

I am working with online shop project. In product model, i have description field but it's empty. Somehow description data is stored in django-cms and autoblocks. From page, i can edit that description with django-cms. In template tag `{% autoblock product.slug %}` line is description.

In views.py, i have 'product' passed as context, but it's slug field has nothing to do with description. Also, if i write `{{ product.slug }}`, it gives me slug.

Also googled about Autoblocks, but what managed to find out it's this model:

```
class Autoblock(models.Model):
    composite_id = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = PlaceholderField('content')
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.composite_id
```

All of these fields has nothing to do with description.

Im struggling for long time to find where that description is. Any hints would be appreciated.

EDITED:

Product model:

```
class HBaseProduct(Product):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HBaseProduct, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, max_length=300,        verbose_name=_('Image'))
    position = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you also share product model ?

Comment: Added it. But model has nothing to do with description in autoblocks

Comment: `{{ product.description }}` should give you the product description

Comment: Yes, if it had one. It's empty now and i need to migrate description from autoblocks to `product.description`. But i can't find that description in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is in `Autoblock.content`, which is a `ForeignKey` to `'cms.Placeholder'`, which in turn holds a tree of `'cms.CMSPlugin'` models in `cmsplugin_set`.

There's currently no straight-forward way to turn a `Placeholder` into a string (of HTML) to be used somewhere else outside of a request/response cycle.

Your best bet is to call `Placeholder.render` with a context object that holds a (fake) Django `Request` object. This will return the rendered contents and you can then store that in `description`.

Comment: Thanks, helped alot. :)